# jupyter notebook not executing codes

Tags: python, jupyter

I starting learning python recently and so far no problem. Yesterday, the jupyter notebook stopped executing code. I have searched online,restarted the kernel, restarted my windows machine and tried to find a way to understand what it is doing so that I can continue, but I have not found a the solution or the reason that my code is not being executed anymore. I am running my code on a windows machine,chrome on windows. I did not intall the jupyter on my machine. I running it off the azure network.

Please help.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Did you press "Shift + Enter" to execute the code

Comment: Maybe you accidently change the type of text from "code" to markdown or something like that. Press "Ctrl + Shift + P" then select "change cell to code" and try again

Comment: The program was an is still in 'code' mode. To execute, we are told to execute via "ctrl + enter". I had done that for the last 3 weeks without problem till now.

Comment: Can you paste the log of jupyter notebook here.

Comment: This is the actual code that I am trying to execute when I discovered that the notebook isn't executing anything at all. Like, its not executing to show errors or success or anything. The code follows next. I have a whole bunch of thing commented out and I am not including those things here . The ones I commented out are in different tabs of the same window that I executed before and was ok with them.

Answer (score 0):

The program was an is still in 'code' mode. To execute, we are told to execute via "ctrl + enter". I had done that for the last 3 weeks without problem till now.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                                                                         import os
```

string_container = ""
add_container = 0
def adding_report(integerToAdd):

## Total = 0

## Total = Total + integerToadd

# add_container = 0

```
while True:
    a = input("Input a number: ")
    if a.digit():
        string_container += a + "\n"
        add_container += int(a)
    else:
        if a == 'A':
            print(Add_container)
        else:
            if a == 'T':
                print(string_container)
            else:

                if a=="q":
                    os._exit(0)
                else:

                    print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. If you write like this, then you can run it for the first time. But from the second time it will not be executed. Because jupyter only clear that code block output, but do not release the while loop.

```
while True:
    a = input("Input a number: ")
    if a.isdigit():
        string_container += a + "\n"
        add_container += int(a)
    else:
        if a == 'A':
            print(Add_container)
        else:
            if a == 'T':
                print(string_container)
            else:

                if a=="q":
                    os._exit(0)
                else:

                    print("invalid input")
```

You should put your code in a try-catch block, like this.

```
try:
    while True:
        a = input("Input a number: ")
        if a.isdigit():
            string_container += a + "\n"
            add_container += int(a)
        else:
            if a == 'A':
                print(Add_container)
            else:
                if a == 'T':
                    print(string_container)
                else:

                    if a=="q":
                        os._exit(0)
                    else:

                        print("invalid input")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

So you have to

```
1. Select restart the kernel and clear output
2. Add try-catch so you can use "kernel interrupt" to kill the while loop
3. Whenever you finish using this while loop, select "kernel" -> "interrupt" to kill it completely
```

Hope that help

Comment: Thank you gentlemen! i am able to execute now. I simply called the function and that did it for me. again, thank you!